# Widget reset after launcher process reload or crash

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher

I have a widget for a player app which displays song metadata including a bitmap and a progressbar.
I'm refreshing the progressbar by broadcasting custom intents to the widget. In that case I only update the progressbar in order to avoid unnecessary computing. Song metada & artwork is only updated when the song changed or when the app receives ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE or ACTION_APPWIDGET_OPTIONS_CHANGED or ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED.
Everything works fine except when I load multiple apps like FB, Chrome and then go back to the launcher screen. For a couple of seconds nothing is displayed on the launcher screen as if it was restarting, then once its done my widget doesn't display any metadata & artwork. I just see the progress bar being updated and once the song changes (or if I press any button on the widget) everything is updated. 
What's happening with the launcher ? Is the process restarting ? If so, why is it not sending ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED or ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE intents ?
Is there a way to detect this kind of launcher behavior so I can send a custom intent to force the whole widget update ?

Comment: We're going to need the whole source code to find the issue :/

Comment: Why would you need the source code ? I'm just asking how to detect a launcher crash/reload and why it's not sending any intent to the installed widgets ?

Comment: Well maybe there's something that can be improve, IDK maybe you are using the wrong type of process name in the manifest or maybe is something related to your device/emulator. Did you experienced the same problems in other devices?